# JSF and EJB together in one app using Intellij

Tags: jsf, ejb, ear

I would like to create JSF and EJB modules but I have no clue how to connect them together or how to create EAR. At the moment I know how to create JSF application but what should I do next? Create EJB module with DAO and enities? Or create DAO and entities in JSF application?

Thanks for help

Comment: Start by learning the concepts WITHOUT IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading the help manual:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-a-java-ee-application.html

Comment: Thanks for help but still I don't know how to do that in correct way. Should I create an empty project only checking Web Application? And later In tab File, New, Module add module with JSF and second module with EJB?

Comment: I am not sure If I create for example Empty project and there I add two modules - JSF and EJB It will create EAR?

Comment: Should I create and empty project or Java EE Application Project ? And then should I add EJB and JSF modules?

Comment: There is no global "correct way", your "correct way" depends on your requirements. Maybe for you is better just a war project with ejb and jsf mixed (if using javaee 7), maybe is better an ear project with ejb submodule and jsf submodule. You need to figure it out.

Comment: I want to recreate way of building app from tutorial. But it was in in eclipse. There were two projects - ejb and jsf and using some tool where you can add modules they created ear.

Comment: That's the right question, folow the second option: an ear project with ejb and jsf submodules.

Comment: Could you check If I did it in correct way? In question I have attached screens of that process.

Comment: Yes that is "your correct" way...